# How to sum a list of tuples by keys

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I wrote the following code to sum by keys :

```
  // ("A", 1)     ("A", 4)
  // ("B", 2) --> ("B", 2)
  // ("A", 3)
  def sumByKeys[A](tuples: List[(A, Long)]) : List[(A, Long)] = {
    tuples.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2).sum).toList
  }
```

Is there a better way ?

**Update** : add `.toList` at the end

Comment: I think this is as good as it gets, I didn't know about that `sum` method, probably would have used a `foldLeft` instead.

Comment: This is the behavior of the semigroup for `Map` in Scalaz, so it would allow you to write `tuples.map(Map(_)).suml.toList`, which isn't necessarily better.

Comment: Note also that you seem to be missing a `toList` at the end.

Comment: Note also that you could use `foldMap` instead of `map` + `suml`: `tuples.foldMap{Map(_)}.toList`, but both `scalaz` method are very inefficient - you'll get `N` `Map` merges.

Comment: Note also that `mapValues` returns a view that applies the transformation on each `get` again.

Comment: @ziggystar: `toList` after `mapValues` solves this problem. Actually it allows you to avoid unnecessary intermediate `Map` creation.

Comment: @senia You're right. `toSeq` also turns it into a strict collection. I thought this behavior was different in the past.

Comment: This is where Haskell's `fromListWith` comes in handy. `fromListWith (+)` does pretty much exactly that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this is the most simple immutable form without usage of any additional framework on top of scala.

**UPD** Actually forgot about final toList. This makes totally different picture in terms of perfomance, because of the mapValues view return type

You can try foldLeft, tailrec, something mutable and they have better perfomance

```
import annotation.tailrec

@tailrec
final def tailSum[A](tuples: List[(A, Long)], acc: Map[A, Long] = Map.empty[A, Long]): List[(A, Long)] = tuples match {
  case (k, v) :: tail => tailSum(tail, acc + (k -> (v + acc.get(k).getOrElse(0L))))
  case Nil => acc.toList
}

def foldLeftSum[A](tuples: List[(A, Long)]) = tuples.foldLeft(Map.empty[A, Long])({
  case (acc, (k, v)) => acc + (k -> (v + acc.get(k).getOrElse(0L)))
}).toList

def mutableSum[A](tuples: List[(A, Long)])  = {
  val m = scala.collection.mutable.Map.empty[A, Long].withDefault(_ => 0L)
  for ((k, v) <- tuples) m += (k -> (v + m(k)))
  m.toList
}
```

Updated perfomance testing is here https://gist.github.com/baskakov/8437895, briefly:

```
scala>     avgTime("default", sumByKeys(tuples))
default avg time is 63 ms

scala>     avgTime("tailrec", tailSum(tuples))
tailrec avg time is 48 ms

scala>     avgTime("foldleft", foldLeftSum(tuples))
foldleft avg time is 45 ms

scala>     avgTime("mutableSum", mutableSum(tuples))
mutableSum avg time is 41 ms
```

Comment: Without the `toList` on `sumByKeys` you're just getting the lazy map returned by `mapValues`, which means you're not doing a chunk of the work your other implementations are.

Comment: Wow. You have just opened my eyes! I guess this is because view on mapvalues? That makes totally different picture

Comment: `mapValues` is weird—it does essentially return a view, but that's not indicated in the return type.

Answer (score 1):

The best I can think of gets you *slightly* better performance and save two characters:

```
def sumByKeys[A](tuples: List[(A, Long)]) : List[(A, Long)] = {
  tuples.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.unzip._2.sum)
}
```

On my machine with Bask.ws' benchmark it took 11ms instead of 13ms without the `unzip`.

**EDIT**: In fact I think the performance must be the same... don't know where those 2ms come from

Comment: 11 ms is just too small. Better increase benchmark parameters at least 5 times (average cycle count and tuples count). This will give more constant and distinguishable values. And don't forget about toList because of mapValues

Answer (score 1):

A solution very similar to yours:

```
def sumByKeys[A](tuples: List[(A, Long)]): List[(A, Long)] =
  tuples groupBy (_._1) map { case (k, v) => (k, v.map(_._2).sum) } toList

val l: List[(String, Long)] = List(("A", 1), ("B", 2), ("A", 3))

sumByKeys(l)
// result:
// List[(String, Long)] = List((A,4), (B,2))
```

What's interesting is that in your solution you use `def mapValues[C](f: (B) ⇒ C): Map[A, C]` which according to docs has "lazy" evaluation: "Transforms this map by applying a function to every retrieved value."

On the other hand `def map[B](f: (A) ⇒ B): Map[B]` will build a new collection: "Builds a new collection by applying a function to all elements of this immutable map."

So depending on your needs you could be lazily evaluating a large map, or eagerly evaluating a small one.

Answer (score 0):

Using reduce,

```
def sumByKeys[A](tuples: List[(A, Long)]): List[(A, Long)] = {
  tuples groupBy(_._1) map { _._2 reduce { (a,b) => (a._1, a._2+b._2) } } toList
}
```

a short for

```
def sumByKeys[A](tuples: List[(A, Long)]): List[(A, Long)] = {
  tuples groupBy(_._1) map { case(k,v) => v reduce { (a,b) => (a._1, a._2+b._2) } } toList
}
```